# airmon-ng / airodump-ng is not detecting any wireless devices

Tags: networking, python, aircrack-ng

I am using ubuntu in vmware and for using airmon-ng, I already download it from terminal.

But when I run it it says

```
root@DESKTOP-SIVJTCS:/home/show# airmon-ng

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

so it doesnt show any interfaces name

then when i run ifconfig and finding my interface name

i run on terminal it says

```
root@DESKTOP-SIVJTCS:/home/show# airmon-ng start wifi0


PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

at last when i run wifite it says

```
root@DESKTOP-SIVJTCS:/home/show# wifite
   .               .
 .´  ·  .     .  ·  `.  wifite2 2.5.2
 :  :  :  (¯)  :  :  :  a wireless auditor by @derv82
 `.  ·  ` /¯\ ´  ·  .´  maintained by kimocoder
   `     /¯¯¯\     ´    https://github.com/kimocoder/wifite2

 [!] Warning: Recommended app bully was not found. install @ https://github.com/aanarchyy/bully
 [!] Warning: Recommended app pyrit was not found. install @ https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit/wiki
 [!] Warning: Recommended app hashcat was not found. install @ https://hashcat.net/hashcat/
 [!] Warning: Recommended app hcxdumptool was not found. install @ https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxdumptool
 [!] Warning: Recommended app hcxpcaptool was not found. install @ https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools

 [+] Checking airmon-ng...
 [!] airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces
 [!] Make sure your wireless device is connected
 [!] See http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng for more info

 [!] Error: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces

 [!] Full stack trace below

 [!]    Traceback (most recent call last):
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 97, in entry_point
 [!]        wifite.start()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/__main__.py", line 50, in start
 [!]        Configuration.get_monitor_mode_interface()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/config.py", line 163, in get_monitor_mode_interface
 [!]        cls.interface = Airmon.ask()
 [!]    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wifite/tools/airmon.py", line 310, in ask
 [!]        raise Exception('airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces')
 [!]  Exception: airmon-ng did not find any wireless interfaces

 [!] Exiting
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the [Wi-Fi driver archive](https://www.mediafire.com/file/5vh3s7v4533wm83/compat-wireless-2010-06-26-p.tar.bz2/file) on your VM.
2. Go to the downloads directory, unpack the archive and step into the unpacked directory.
3. Run the following commands:

   ```
   make unload
   make load
   ```